# Python - Hits per minute implementation?

Tags: python

This seems like such a trivial problem, but I can't seem to pin how I want to do it. Basically, I want to be able to produce a figure from a socket server that at any time can give the number of packets received in the last minute. How would I do that?

I was thinking of maybe summing a dictionary that uses the current second as a key, and when receiving a packet it increments that value by one, as well as setting the second+1 key above it to 0, but this just seems sloppy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say the last minute, do you mean the exact last seconds or the last full minute from x:00 to x:59? The latter will be easier to implement and would probably give accurate results. You have one prev variable holding the value of the hits for the previous minute. Then you have a current value that increments every time there is a new hit. You return the value of prev to the users. At the change of the minute you swap prev with current and reset current.

If you want higher analysis you could split the minute in 2 to 6 slices. You need a variable or list entry for every slice. Let's say you have 6 slices of 10 seconds. You also have an index variable pointing to the current slice (0..5). For every hit you increment a temp variable. When the slice is over, you replace the value of the indexed variable with the value of temp, reset temp and move the index forward. You return the sum of the slice variables to the users.

Answer (score 3):

A common pattern for solving this in other languages is to let the thing being measured simply increment an integer. Then you leave it to the listening client to determine intervals and frequencies.

So you basically do *not* let the socket server know about stuff like "minutes", because that's a feature the observer calculates. Then you can also support multiple listeners with different interval resolution.

I suppose you want some kind of ring-buffer structure to do the rolling logging.

Comment: This is how linux handles reporting traffic, seems pretty sane to me.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, your implementation above won't work if you don't receive a packet every second, as the next second entry won't necessarily be reset to 0.

Either way, afaik the "correct" way to do this, ala logs analysis, is to keep a limited record of all the queries you receive. So just chuck the query, time received etc. into a database, and then simple database queries will give you the use over a minute, or any minute in the past. Not sure whether this is too heavyweight for you, though.